# oracle 11g listagg with reference id

Tags: sql, oracle11g

one table lists a variety of employee_ids with any one job.

the employee names are listed in a separate table.  Action names are also in an additional table.

the listagg statement to aggregate the employee ids is simple enough, but the need is to list the employee names.

Additionally, the action id within each job needs to be associated with the employee for the action.

```
  select job.id,
      listagg(hist.empl_id, ',') within group (order by job.id) as emp_list,
      listagg(hist.ACTION_ID, ',') within group (order by job.id) as     actionid_list
 from jobs job,
      job_action_log hist           
where  job.id = hist.job_id 
      group by job.id;
```

this is correctly returning the jobid, aggregated empid and aggregated action id.

```
job   employee       action
-------------------------------
14   9, 12, 14, 9  5, 7, 88, 5
```

what is needed is to return the employee name from the employee table, an action name from another table listing action id and the names of the actions, and to associate the proper employee with the correct action.

desired results:

```
    jobid  employee name          action
    ------------------------------------------------------
     14    Bob, Joe, Sam, Linda   sweep, glass, mop, sweep
```

any suggestions or assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `join` the other two tables and select the required fields (change them to be appropriate) in `listagg`. Also, you should stop using old-style joins.

```
select 
job.id,
listagg(e.employee_name, ',') within group (order by job.id) as emp_list,
listagg(a.action_name, ',') within group (order by job.id) as actionid_list
from jobs job 
join job_action_log hist on job.id = hist.job_id 
join actions a on a.id = hist.action_id
join employees e on e.employee_id = hist.empl_id
group by job.id;
```